# Connecting a line through a scatter in a particular order

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've drawn a plot of 20 points on matplotlib
However, applying a '-o' parameter on the plot causes the plots to be connected in a weird order.
I would like it connected along the x axis (lowest x to highest x)

It currently looks like this

[image: Only plot, no -o]

This is what it looks like with '-o'

[image]

Is there a way to force matplotlib to plot in increasing order of x values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Sort the points in increasing order of `x`-coordinates before giving those points to matplotlib, which simply connects the points in the order you give them to matplotlib.

(We could help you more if you show us the code, perhaps simplified, that gave you that bad example plot.)

Comment: You were right this works!

I figured out another issue with my code was that the wrong x and y coordinates were being fed in hence the bad plot as well.